# kineticjs shape based on left and top coordinates

Tags: kineticjs

I have a kineticjs stage and one layer with a Path object defined in it. I have never been able to get the Path to show on my canvas. For some reason it looks like the canvas/stage does not respect the x and y coordinates of the parent div. What is the solution to this?
I have also tried to set the x and y coordinates of the stage and path objects but no luck. 
Here is what I am trying

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container : id,
  width : 105,
  height : 165
});
var path = new Kinetic.Path({
  data : "M176.0,463.0 L228.0,462.0 228.0,452.0 275.0,452.0 275.0,330.0 A40.0,0.0 0.0 1,1 254.0,295.0 L171.0,326.0 170.0,463.0z",
  fill : 'rgba(100, 15, 56, 0.5)',
  scale : 2,
  x : 176,
  y: 295
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
layer.add(path);
stage.add(layer);
```

Note that my path geom starts from 176,463. Although the parent div is in the right place, the shape never gets drawn inside this div. any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

**The X and Y coordinates in KineticJS are relative to the stage, not the parent div's page XY.**

Therefore, your path drawing is there, it’s just wa-a-a-a-ay offstage.

You can see this if you set your path to a scale and x/y that will fit in the stage:

```
    var path = new Kinetic.Path({
      data : "M176.0,463.0 L228.0,462.0 228.0,452.0 275.0,452.0 275.0,330.0 A40.0,0.0 0.0 1,1 254.0,295.0 L171.0,326.0 170.0,463.0z",
      fill : 'rgba(100, 15, 56, 0.5)',
      scale : .25,
      x : 5,
      y: 5
    });
```

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ZMDYy/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:105px;
  height:165px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 105,
        height: 165
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var path = new Kinetic.Path({
      data : "M176.0,463.0 L228.0,462.0 228.0,452.0 275.0,452.0 275.0,330.0 A40.0,0.0 0.0 1,1 254.0,295.0 L171.0,326.0 170.0,463.0z",
      fill : 'rgba(100, 15, 56, 0.5)',
      scale : .25,
      x : 5,
      y: 5
    });
    layer.add(path);
    layer.draw();



}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the direction. All I had to do was set my scale to 1 and negate the coordinates to get the shape inside the canvas.